# css modules with 3rd packages css

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

here is my original webpack setting

```
{ test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']},
```

if I want to use css modules, I need to edit my setting to

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    ]
  }
```

But I got problem with 3rd party packages

One is the `import 'rc-collapse/assets/index.css';`  not work

And another is I have some css like

```
.Popover-body {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*padding: 2rem 4rem;*/
  /*background: hsl(0, 0%, 27%);*/
  background: #B1C5D0;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  /*border: 1px;*/
}
```

It's in the Package `react-popover` , I overwrite its css, but css modules can't read it

I think it is because I didnot write something like `className={styles[Popover-body]}`

But It's a 3rd party package, I don know where to add `className={styles[Popover-body]}`

How could css read both normal css(`loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']}`) and css modules (`loaders: [
            'style?sourceMap',
            'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]`)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran to this issue today.  Had to do a bunch of things- note order of lines and even string matters.

1. Ensure you are requiring your css file in your JSX/Componenet like so:

   `import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import 'rc-collapse/assets/index.css';
   import Collapse, {Panel} from 'rc-collapse';`
2. Make sure your webpack.config.js includes node modules for css

   `module: {
   loaders: [{
     test: /\.css$/,
     include: /node_modules/,
     loaders: [
       'style?sourceMap',
       'css'
     ]
   }, {
     test: /\.css$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loaders: [
       'style?sourceMap',
       'css?modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
     ]
   }, {
     test: /\.jsx?$/,
     loader: 'babel',
     include: SRC_DIR,
     exclude: /node_modules/
   }, {
     test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
     loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
   }, {
     test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
     loader: 'file-loader',
   }]
   }`

This fixed it for me and i was able to get the css for the rc-collapse component that i installed and add on my own styles.  Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I try. this can solve the problem `import 'rc-collapse/assets/index.css';`  but the popover part still is a problem